# View of UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad

I am trying to put a `UIViewController`'s view on my window object (in AppDelegate).

```
splitViewController = [[SplitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplitViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
```

What I did, i made an .xib with .h and .m, a subclass of `UIViewController`. Then I inserted a `UISplitViewController`'s object to my xib and made a same iVAR `@property (strong) IBOutlet UISplitViewController *split;` and connected them. But now I want to link `UISplitViewController`'s view to File's Owner's view. But it's not allowing me to do so.

What's the reason behind it? Please solve, Thanks!

**EDIT**

Then I tried to put this code in viewDidLoad of `SplitViewController`:

```
self.view = self.split.view;
```

But again application crashes and gives following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SplitViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: Follow the warning.  Set your view outlet in the nib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the view outlet in your XIB.  The warnings aren't all jibberish.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do the same. But when I drop the view outlet on _UISplitViewController_'s object, it doesn't allow me to do so. Though I can set the view outlet to some TableView or any other view, that is successfully driven. Can't I set my view outlet to _UISplitViewController_'s object?

Comment: Specifically because it's a UISplitViewControllee object, not a UIView object.  Drag in a UIView, or set the view outlet to one of the two required view controller's views.